# Store shell output in variable

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm new to prolog and trying to use the `Shell` function to read in values to a variable. What i'm trying to do is this:

1. Run shell command that outputs 0 to many lines
2. Store output in variable
3. Continue with actions on variables

This would be the equivalent of something like this

```
$ find ./ -name "example*"
./example1
./example2

$ ls -la ./example1
$ ls -la ./example2
```

I can do the first part

`find_files() :- shell("find ./ -name \"example*\" 2>/dev/null").`

How would you then take each of the lines, e.g. `./example1` and `./example2` and then store them in a variable to run in another function?

Something like this? `run_ls` doesn't work properly with this but that's the logic i'm trying to implement.

```
concatenate(StringList, StringResult) :-
    maplist(atom_chars, StringList, Lists),
    append(Lists, List),
    atom_chars(StringResult, List).

run_ls(X) :- shell(concatenate(["ls ", X], String)).

find_files :- shell("find ./ -name \"example*\" 2>/dev/null"), run_ls(output_variable_from_shell).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want to use [process_create/3](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=process_create/3) not shell/1 or [shell/2](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=shell/2).

You can then capture whatever the child process writes to its standard output or standard error via a pipe.

On the `process_create/3` page, Boris gives this example to capture output:

```
bash_command(Command, Output) :-
        process_create(path(bash),
                ['-c', Command],
                [stdout(pipe(Out))]),
        read_string(Out, _, Output),
        close(Out).
```

And with this:

```
?- bash_command("echo banana | tr na bo", Output).
Output = "bobobo\n".
```

For `find`, it is best to have it print paths separated by the 0 character:

```
find . -print0
```

You can then safely & easily split the large string obtained at the `\x00` character into a list of paths, while not having to care about whitespace, or CR/LF in pathnames (well, I think so, it might not work for reasons).

Comment: This answer didn't directly answer my question, although it helped me realize what i wasn't understanding and also helped me improve on my problem. My question was about storing the output of a variable and I didn't realize that `String` in `shell(concatenate(["ls ", X], String)).` was the output variable, I thought it was the type. Thanks!